# How to use Google Analytics with AngularFire?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-analytics, angularfire, google-analytics-firebase

I have an Angular app build with AngularFire and hosted on Firebase. 
How should I be using Analytics SDK to set the user ID, track page loads and log custom events?

Comment: This blog could be helpful: https://arunraj6.medium.com/angular8-10-with-firebase-analytics-7667bf63c6b1

Answer (score 45, accepted):

AngularFire is now supporting Firebase Analytics since [version 5.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/v5/CHANGELOG.md#530-2020-01-07).

You can update your dependencies :

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
"firebase": "^7.8.0"
```

As mentioned by [AngularFire Docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/v5/docs/analytics/getting-started.md), you just have to add `AngularFireAnalyticsModule` :

```
import { AngularFireAnalyticsModule } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Be sure to add your `appId` and `measurementId` to your config file. (retrieve from Firebase Console, after enabling Analytics).

Comment: Run npm -v @angular/fire and nom -v firebase to check your current version installed

Comment: In later versions of AngularFire `AngularFireAnalyticsModule` moved to `@angular/fire/compat/analytics`.

Comment: @MikePoole do you know if there is none compat import that we should be using instead now? I see there is a `import { AnalyticsModule } from "@angular/fire/analytics";` available now.

Answer (score 3):

Support for Firebase Analytics is coming to AngularFire https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2178